# Boundedness and Schrödinger operators

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-calculus

I'm working on Schrödinger operators, currently struggling with the proof of $\nabla(\Delta + i)^{-1/2}$ bounded. The domain is $H^2(\mathbb R^3)$.

So, of course $(\Delta + i)^{-1}$ is bounded, and so is its square root - but how do I handle the nabla? The fact is given as obvious, and I think I'm missing something **big** here.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calculating $(\Delta+i)^{-1}$? Shouldnt be that hard.

Comment: Is that the only way? I was trying to avoid all the Fourier transform pain

Comment: Probably not, but for sure the most obvious and straightforward way :)

Comment: Hint for another way: $(\Delta f,f)=-\|\nabla f\|^{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some offline help by Daniel and thanks to the last comment, I think the riddle is solved by the following:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\langle\nabla(\Delta+i)^{-1}\psi, (\Delta + i)^{-1}\psi\rangle = \langle(-\Delta)(\Delta+i)^{-1}\psi, (\Delta+i)^{-1}\psi\rangle = \\
&= \langle(\Delta+i)^{-1}(-\Delta)(\Delta+i)^{-1}\psi, \psi\rangle\leq ||(\Delta+i)^{-1}||\cdot||\Delta(\Delta+i)^{-1}||\cdot||\psi||^2
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Also observing $||\Delta(\Delta+i)^{-1}||<+\infty$ by
\begin{equation}
\Delta(\Delta+i)^{-1} = \int_{\mathbb R_+}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + i}dE_{\Delta}(\lambda)
\end{equation}

I'd still appreciate some external feedback on the solution. Is this correct?

**Edit:** still working on this: for the sake of clarity, I will add some further computation. By the last equation
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
||\Delta(\Delta+i)^{-1}(\psi)|| &= ||\int_{\mathbb R_+}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + i}dE_{\Delta}(\lambda)(\psi)||=\\
&= (2\pi)^{-3/2}||\int_{\mathbb R_+}\int_{|k|=\sqrt\lambda}\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + i}\hat{\psi}(k)\exp(ik\cdot x)d^3kd\lambda||\leq \\
&\leq (2\pi)^{-3/2}\int_{\mathbb R_+}\big|\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + i}\big|\cdot ||\int_{|k|=\sqrt\lambda}\hat{\psi}(k)\exp(ik\cdot x)d^3k||d\lambda \leq \\
&\leq || (2\pi)^{-3/2}\int_{\mathbb R^3}\hat{\psi}(k)\exp(ik\cdot x)d^3k|| = ||\psi||
\end{split}
\end{equation}
This would really settle things down.